# iOS Swift DispatchQueue: How do I run a process using multiple CPUs

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, swift4, grand-central-dispatch

### Please note this is **Swift 4**

So far I am trying to run the Grand Central Dispatch to process images on multiple cores.

The issue I am running into is that the processing only occurs on the main queue and stays on the first core.

I am using an iPhone 6 which has dual cores up to 200% cpu I can use and it caps out at 100% CPU and other threads are clearly not running the function.

**CODE**:

```
//value is an image inside an image array that I am using the .map function
//imageProcess processes an image on the device CPU.

                let core1 = DispatchQueue(label: "core1", qos: .userInitiated)
                let core2 = DispatchQueue(label: "core2", qos: .userInitiated)

                core1.async {

                    self.imageProcess(fromImage: value, completion: { (error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Oops something failed!")
                        }
                        else {
                            print("It has finished! Core1")
                        }
                    })
                }
                core2.async{
                    self.imageProcess(fromImage: value, completion: { (error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Oops something failed!")
                        }
                        else {
                            print("It has finished! Core2")
                        }
                    })
                }
```

What I am seeing is the DispatchQueue just drops everything into thread 11 on my CPU and all the images are processed that way. There is no multithreading and it stays on a single core.

**Questions:**

1. Do I need to dump the function inside the dispatch queue?
2. Does anyone have a snippet with DispatchQueue I can test for running a iOS device up to 200% CPU?

Thanks all!

**Update**

Looks like my function is not properly configured for DispatchQueue. Any suggestions?

Please note that faceDetector is calling a firebase function [MLKit Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/detect-faces)

```
private func imageProcess(fromImage image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    let visionImage = VisionImage(image: image)
    faceDetector.detect(in: visionImage) { [unowned self] (faces, error) in
        guard error == nil, let detectedFaces = faces else {
            self.showAlert("An error occured", alertMessage: "The face detection failed.")
            return
        }

        let faceStates = self.faceStates(forDetectedFaces: detectedFaces)
        self.updateDetectedInfo(forFaceStates: faceStates)
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try a lower priority `qos` or create your own queue using `let core1 = DispatchQueue(label: "core1", qos: .background)`

Comment: Just tried it, not seeing a difference, CPU was still 100%/200%. If you put prints inside the core1.async and core2.async it'll jump through them before the self.imageProcess() completes.

Comment: Is `imageProcess` async itself?

Comment: The firebase function inside the imageProcessing function is synchronous.

Comment: There's your problem. `detect` is async so `imageProcess` returns immediately. Your use of `core1.async` and `core2.async` is pointless at the moment since `imageProcess returns immediately while `detect` runs in the background on whatever queue is it written to use.

Comment: So you are saying that the .detect method from firebase is running on a background process that I can't override and I won't be able to put it on a different thread?

Comment: I don't know anything about Firebase or whatever `faceDetector` is (other than `detect` is async) so I have no idea if it provides any way to specify the queue it is run on.